# Why is my Symfony 2 cache warmer called multiple times?

Tags: php, symfony, caching

One of my bundles in a Symfony 2 application has a custom cache warmer.

When run from the console and in dev mode, it writes a notification to stdout that it has been called.

Sometimes, not always, it is called multiple times for a single console cache:clear command as evidenced by multiple notifications being written to stdout.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Is it normal? Are all of the cache warmers called Multiple times?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3
- PHP 7.0.2-4
- Symfony 2.7.9

------ Edit 21-Feb-2016 08:36 -------

It is impractical to post by actual source for various reasons (size, NDAs, etc.) So, I've created a tiny little bundle with cache warmer that just echos its class name when called.

As you can see in the output below, it is called twice.

```
//
// The cache warmer.
//
namespace SoBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerInterface;

class CacheWarmer implements CacheWarmerInterface
{
    public function isOptional()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function warmUp( $cacheDir )
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . '()' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

#
# The service definition.
#
services:
    so.cache_warmer:
        class: SoBundle\Listener\CacheWarmer
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.cache_warmer }

#
# Clearing the cache...
#
$ console cache:clear
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
SoBundle\Listener\CacheWarmer()
SoBundle\Listener\CacheWarmer()
```

Comment: impossible to help you without your bundle custom cache warmer code...

Comment: Why on earth do you need my warmer source code. It implements the standard stuff: isOptional() returns false. warmUp() builds my cache. Then, of course there is the service definition which specifies the class name, the constructor arguments, and kernel.cache_warmer as the value of the name tag.

Comment: Post your code and what you've tried.  Is it your custom cache warmer?  Is it from a 3rd-party bundle?  Are there any particular cases you've discovered where it is called multiple times and not others?  If you're looking for help, help us help you by providing more details.

Comment: Okay. I've posted code.

Comment: I ran into this a few months ago and found an explanation for this behaviour but... I can't remember it anymore. I will bookmark your question and will provide and answer if I remember what it was :) .

Comment: @RaduMurzea, I hope you remember. I haven't been able to find an answer it it's driving me a bit crazy (a short drive :-). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPatterson Nope, I haven't forgotten. I'm actually pretty close :) . From what I can tell up to this point is that it's probably an intentional behaviour...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single execution of `console cache:clear` can trigger cache warming **between 0 and 3 times**, depending on these factors:

1. Current state of cache,
2. Optional parameters (e.g. `--no-warmup` and `--no-optional-warmers`),
3. Whether a cache warmer is optional (as per `isOptional()` method).

A little intro: Symfony uses a service named `cache_warmer` which is mapped to `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate` class. It is used to aggregate all registered cache warming services tagged with `kernel.cache_warmer` and it provides convenient methods for executing them.

There are 2 methods where cache warming is initiated explicitly during `console cache:clear` call:

1. `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::initializeContainer()` - executed with every kernel initialization, whether in console or web mode. It triggers non-optional cache warmers if you don't have a warm cache.
2. `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand::warmup()` - executed by `console cache:clear` command. It triggers all or only optional warmers depending on the used options. *But more importantly*, it actually creates a temporary kernel via `$this->getTempKernel()` which also triggers non-optional cache warmers during initialization (as in point above).

That gets you **between 0-3 calls** to each cache warming service. Based on Symfony v2.8.3.

P.S. It only took 2 hours of digging through Symfony code, out of curiosity ;)

Comment: That seems a bit inefficient, but since cache warming only happens once for each production release, I guess it's reasonable. Thanks for taking the time to dig that out. My familiarity with the Symfony internals isn't quite that good yet.